# Why are types declared in value constructors not types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-declaration, value-constructor

Suppose I have the following value constructor:

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float
```

Now I can run:

```
ghci> :t Circle
Circle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Shape
```

Now I can write a type declaration

```
surface :: Shape -> Float
```

But I can't type a type declaration

```
surface :: Circle -> Float
```

This [is because](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) "`Circle` is not a type, `Shape` is"

My question is: **Why are types declared in value constructors not types in Haskell?**

Comment: "Types declared in value constructors" makes no sense. They're not types so they're definitely not "types declared in value constructors". They're data constructors. You also can't write the function `surface :: 13 -> 1.2`.

Comment: The syntax for `data` is a historical accident.  Use the GADT syntax for a more consistent way to give types to constructors.

Comment: @augustss ... it's not really an accident - I think GADTs are not even in the standard yet (not that it matters too much)

Comment: instead of concentrating on the `Shape` I would look at what you want to do with them - that is the operations like `surface` - if you want to abstract this you could write functions to collect those into a record (or another data structure) or create a type-class for those - TL;DR: OOP = collect nouns / FP = collect verbs

Comment: @Carsten It's a historical accident in the sense that it was influenced by other languages at the time of the design, like Miranda, LML, and Orwell.  These in turn where influenced by Hope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float
```

`Shape` is a type (and a type constructor). `Float` is another type.

`Circle` and `Rectangle` are the value constructors for type `Shape`.

I guess that your confusion comes from OOP subtyping -- note that Haskell has no analogous to that. The above does not declare two types `Circle` and `Rectangle` to be subtypes of `Shape`.

Using some advanced extensions like `GADTs` you can actually write something like `foo :: Circle -> Float` meaning that the argument is a `Shape` value which has been constructed as a `Circle`. This requires some type-level techniques.

Alternatively, a plain Haskell approach could be

```
data Circle = Circle Float Float Float
data Rectangle = Rectangle Float Float Float Float
data Shape = Scircle Circle | Srectangle Rectangle
```